# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

При попытке привести тип данных в числовые выскакивает ошибка. Данные берутся XML из http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree


resp = etree.fromstring(requests.get("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp").text.encode("1251"))
curs_1 = resp.find("Valute[@ID='R01135']/Value").text
curs_2 = resp.find("Valute[@ID='R01535']/Value").text

curs_3 = int(curs_2 / curs_1)

print(f"Одна норвежская крона равна {curs_2}  {curs_1} Венгерских форинтов")
```

Вывод

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\Skillfactory\Forint.py", line 9, in <module>
    curs_3 = int(curs_2 / curs_1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Перед попыткой привести строковые данные в числовые происходит попытка разделить строку на строку... Именно об этом написано в ошибке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curs_3 = int(curs_2 / curs_1)
```

- Преобразовывать в числа нужно обе переменные по отдельности
- Преобразовывать нужно в числа с плавающей точкой, а не в целые числа
- Нужно поменять в строках знак `,` на `.` перед преобразованием

```
curs_3 = float(curs_2.replace(',','.')) / float(curs_1.replace(',','.'))
print(curs_3)
# 3.3617511336142663
```

Comment: Спасибо! Float пробовал применять, но вместе с int.

Comment: @Ivan Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как решение, если оно помогло Вам.